# How to unblock a connected app in Salesforce when the unblock button is disabled

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

I can't unblock some apps on my Salesforce connected app admin. If you look at the app highlighed with yellow background on the page bottom. The unblock button is disabled. Why?

[image]

Answer (score -2):

From the Salesforce [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.identityImplGuide.meta/identityImplGuide/identity_report_monitor.htm):

> Unblock—Give users access to the connected app. By unblocking the app, users can log in and run the app. **If Unblock is disabled, the app is blocked org-wide because it’s not whitelisted**. To whitelist the app, click Install. Then click Edit Policies, and under the app’s OAuth settings, set Permitted Users to Admin approved users are pre-authorized. You can whitelist apps only if you’ve asked Salesforce to enable the API client whitelisting feature

Comment: But the app is not a Salesforce app but an Salesforce OAuth APP. I has nothing to install.

Comment: You are not installing the app per say, it's more of giving your the ability to manage  the app  as a connected app by setting policies for access in salesforce.